# "consent" vs "assent"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What's the difference between the verbs "assent" and "consent"?
In this context, if we replace the verb "consent" with its synonym, "assent", would the result sound *okay*, *awkward*, or *incorrect*?

> Her father reluctantly **consented** to the marriage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would definitely be a bit *“awkward”*. These are not exactly synonyms.

True, in either case, the father could be said to be agreeing to the marriage, but in the example above he’s [*giving permission*](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+consent) and in the proposed alternative he’s [*expressing approval*](http://www.google.com/search?q=define+assent), which would require that he agree *with* the marriage—that he love the whole idea—which he clearly does not.

The verb form of “assent” has all but fallen out of use, as far as I’m aware. Most people would simply say “approve of” instead of “assent to” although there is use in legal contexts where a party (a judge, say) would be referred to as assenting or dissenting, regarding the decision at which the group has arrived.

Comment: I certainly agree *assent* here would be at best "awkward", but I'm not convinced the *consent/assent* distinction is concerned with *permission/approval*. OED says it's that *assent* implies *to agree to an **abstract proposition**, or a proposal **that does not concern oneself, or involve one's own action.*** That seems right to me, in that *consenting* usually implies accepting that something will be *done to **you***. But *assenting* usually just means accepting in the sense of *agreeing* (or simply, *not disagreeing*) with some statement/proposition.

Comment: I appreciate the nuance added, but I think the idea of permission already implies that sense of domain. The example given here is a good one in this respect. Nobody's marrying the father, and yet, due to cultural convention, he is considered an affected party (who, for this reason, is in a position to permit or bar the union). I like the idea of using “assent” in reference to abstract propositions, but it doesn't seem to be used that way commonly as far as I can tell, so I don't see myself making much use of it.

Comment: I assent to this answer.

Comment: @ Tyler: OED says of the verb form *assent*: *archaic in general sense, and commonly replaced by **consent**, except. as said of the sovereign assenting to a measure, or as in #4* (where #4 is that definition I gave above). (There are several other closely-related definitions, all explicitly flagged as *obsolete*.) The main thing for OP to take on board is that in practice [we simply don't use "assent" in his context](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=assented+to+the+marriage%2Cconsented+to+the+marriage&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Comment: I like OED's final citation for that sense #4: *1874   F. Hall in N. Amer. Rev. 119 329   **Assenting to the premises, we reject the conclusion**.* It sounds a bit starchy/dated to me (well, I suppose it would, wouldn't it?), but in that exact context I think *consent* would be even more weird.